# Arch linux : how to keep wifi connected while sleep/hibernate mode arch linux?

Tags: node.js, linux, arch

I have a automated nodejs script that requires my local machine to stay connected to wifi, but when my machine goes into sleep/hibernate mode the wifi disconnect and cause failing of the service, solutions?

Comment: if the computer is asleep the service will be asleep too, the solution is to keep it on

Comment: thany you @drescherjm